# How to upload images in server from binary data using NodeJS or ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

I need to upload images in server using NodeJS/ExpressJS. But the image will be sent in binary format from client side. Previously I used to do with multer. Do multer support binary data upload? Or any other way?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Image files are always sent in binary, and so multer (and all other file upload libraries) support that. For that matter you could handle the whole thing at the protocol or socket level yourself, but why bother?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about the 'binary format' you intend to use. It might help to include the relevant client code.